# Enum database mapping in Apex?

Tags: apex, force.com, database.com

I want to work with Enums in my Apex code and I'm wondering what the usual practice is for storing their value in a database.  Like java, you shouldn't store the ordinal as an int because that could change if you edit the Enum.  Storing the value as a string is the obvious thing but there appears to be no valueOf(enum_name) method to take us back from the String to the Enum.

Does everyone doing this just write something like this because there is nothing built in?

http://wordgraphs.com/post/2910/Convert-string-to-enum-in-Apex

or is there a more intuitive way to store a selected enum element in the database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally an enum would map to the picklist field type, and in that case I've seen a few implementations for dealing with this, some people just use string literals in their code - however that gets inflexible and hard to maintain very quickly.

Others use wrapper classes that have something like a .toSObject() method that marshalls the data into the SObject type, which would generally do this type of mapping.

I haven't seen it used to date, but you could use the [Schema.PicklistEntry](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_Schema_PicklistEntry.htm) values for your field directly in your code, since they have a few advantages over enums:

- New picklist values get a corresponding PickListEntry instance automatically - no code needed
- They're a richer data type that can keep track of a few properties beyond what an enum can.
- The getLabel() method will handle any localized translations for you, if any.
- If somebody uses the API to set a picklist to an abitrary string (yes, you can do that) it shows up as an inactive picklist value, rather than failing to find a corresponding enum type.

However since you're limited to 100 getPicklistValues calls per transaction you'd be wise to build some sort of caching system if you use this pattern on a large scale app.